# How to have Case Syntax in the IF Condition Join Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to have Case Syntax in the IF Condition Join Query ?

How to have these two blocks of select query in a single case else statement?

```
declare @provid int
declare @stageprovid int

-- If this Syntax satisfies, then don't execute the next syntax.
-- If this syntax does not satisfy, then execute the next block.

SELECT @provid = prv.ID 
FROM StagingProvider StagePrv
JOIN Providers prv 
ON StagePrv.ClientID = prv.ClientID 
AND  prv.ExternalProviderID = StagePrv.[Provider_ID]
WHERE StagePrv.ID = @stageprovid;  

-- This block of syntax executes only if the first block did not satisfy.    

SELECT @provid = prv.ID 
FROM StagingProvider StagePrv   
JOIN Providers prv
ON StagePrv.ClientID = StagePrv.ClientID 
AND prv.NPI = StagePrv.NPI
WHERE StagePrv.ID = @stageprovid;
```

Comment: the question is not really very clear. we need to understand what the table looks like and what parameters you want to pass into provid and  stageprovid.

Comment: @MEdwin, sorry for that. I made changes. Please review

Comment: Are you familiar with `if` syntax ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @GordonLinoff , if you could be with it. would be better

Comment: What measureable quality would determine if the first block "satisfies"?

Comment: Very simple question.. i am not sure and so i am asking. Can we have case statement in the join query ?

Comment: Yes, you can "have case statement in the join query".

Comment: so next question is.. if i can have case statement, i am expecting this two separate block of query in a single case statement

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure I finally understand what you're trying to ask, and the answer is No, you cannot use a CASE expression the way you are thinking of, to control a JOIN condition.

The way you can do what you want, if I have understood you correctly, is to use an OR in the JOIN condition, and use TOP 1 with ORDER BY to prioritize the result to the correct one:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @provid = prv.ID 
FROM StagingProvider StagePrv
JOIN Providers prv 
ON StagePrv.ClientID = prv.ClientID 
AND (
 prv.ExternalProviderID = StagePrv.[Provider_ID]
 OR prv.NPI = StagePrv.NPI
 )
WHERE StagePrv.ID = @stageprovid
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN prv.ExternalProviderID = StagePrv.[Provider_ID] THEN 0
  ELSE 1
END;
```

Another, probably better, approach would have been to use a UNION, but I think this is probably closer to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading this that if you can find an ID under the first join condition, you are good. If you cannot, then you need to proceed to the second join condition. If this is the case, you can try joining twice to your table. In this case, if there is no ID on the first join, you pick up the ID on the second join.

```
SELECT @provid = COALESCE(first.ID, second.ID) 
FROM StagingProvider StagePrv
LEFT JOIN Providers prv AS first
  ON StagePrv.ClientID = prv.ClientID 
     AND  prv.ExternalProviderID = StagePrv.[Provider_ID]  
LEFT JOIN Providers prv AS second
  ON StagePrv.ClientID = StagePrv.ClientID 
     AND prv.NPI = StagePrv.NPI
WHERE StagePrv.ID = @stageprovid;
```

Note that this could be written as a CASE, if you very much want to do so:

```
SELECT @provid = CASE WHEN first.ID IS NOT NULL 
                      THEN first.ID
                      ELSE second.ID 
                      END
FROM StagingProvider StagePrv
LEFT JOIN Providers prv AS first
  ON StagePrv.ClientID = prv.ClientID 
     AND  prv.ExternalProviderID = StagePrv.[Provider_ID]  
LEFT JOIN Providers prv AS second
  ON StagePrv.ClientID = StagePrv.ClientID 
     AND prv.NPI = StagePrv.NPI
WHERE StagePrv.ID = @stageprovid;
```